# LLVM: How to access JIT API at runtime & edit myself?

Tags: jit, llvm

could you suggest if that's possible to access LLVM JIT API from the program being executed? My goal is to be able to manipulate(add/update/remove) classes, methods and data on the fly.

Preferably, I would stay with Clang. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be pretty easy stuff. In the JIT you can provide a mapping between any external function to the arbitrary address. So, basically you'll just define some function in your IR being JITed, bind it to the address in the outside world and this will make a trick for you.

In particular,  http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ExecutionEngine.html#a805704b52a327cc6b37aebf9cba14169 is the function you should use here.

Comment: I.e. I will have to build custom interpreter/JIT-compiler which will be exposing required methods from JIT API for my software running under VM? Also, this binds just 1 global variable, but JIT API is object oriented, I am not sure we can make it work that easy :-|

Comment: It's a GlobalValue, not GlobalVariable. GlobalValue is a base class for both Function and GlobalVariable, so you can bind both (and arbitrary amount - just call the function for all the objects you're wanting to bind). And yes, LLVM is written in C++, so you will need to live with C++ ABI. Alternatively, you can use the C bindings and bind them. Look inside http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/include/llvm-c/ExecutionEngine.h?view=markup to have an idea of what it's going on.